# How to set up ACL by not using RBAC in ADLS gen2?

Tags: azure, acl, azure-data-lake-gen2

Please let me know how did you set up the ACL by not using RBAC. I tried the below steps:

Created a user in Active Directory
In Storage(Gen2) -> IAM -> Gave the reader access to the user
In Storage Explorer - > Right click on the root folder -> manage access - > Giving Read, Write and execute permission.
Still this is not working. I guess since i have given reader role in IAM, ACL is not getting applied.

However if i do not set read access in IAM. User is unable to see the storage account when he is logging to the Azure portal. Please Let me know how shall i apply ACL ?

I have 5 folders. I want to give rwx access to 3 folders for DE team and rx access to DS team.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0):

If you use ACL to access ADLS Gen2 via Azure portal, it is impossible. Because in Azure portal, in default users will use account key to access ADLS Gen2. So users should have permission to list the account key. But ACL cannot do that. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-access-blobs-queues-portal?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json).  If you want to use ACL, I suggest you use [azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10).

For example

My ADLS Gen2

```
FileSystem
  test
  folder
    result_csv
```

I want to list all files in the folder result_csv.

1. Configure ACL. For more details about ACL, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control)

```
Operation               /         result_csv/

list /result_csv        --x       r-x
```

2. Test

```
azcopy login --tenant-id <your tenant>
azcopy list "your url"
```

[image]